# SPF/DKIM Configuration for usage with critsend

Tags: email, spf, dkim

I am currently facing the following issue:

I have configured a domain of mine to be used with the Critsend mailing service. Their recommended configuration for both SPF and DKIM was implemented on our system and still when we send an email with their system it still shows that it was sent by critsend.com rather than [MYDOMAIN]:

`Delivered-To:[SOMEBODY]
Received: by 10.194.154.227 with SMTP id vr3csp97881wjb;
        Tue, 25 Feb 2014 01:30:42 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.190.10 with SMTP id gm10mr1147551wjc.55.1393320642547;
        Tue, 25 Feb 2014 01:30:42 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: nicolas@critsend.com
Received: from sender17.critsend.com (sender17.critsend.com. [88.191.188.23])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id ev4si41533wib.66.2014.02.25.01.30.42
        for [SOMEBODY];
        Tue, 25 Feb 2014 01:30:42 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of nicolas@critsend.com designates 88.191.188.23 as permitted sender) client-ip=88.191.188.23;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of nicolas@critsend.com designates 88.191.188.23 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=nicolas@critsend.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@[MYDOMAIN]
Received: from sender17.critsend.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by sender17.critsend.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4789D31C1091
    for [SOMEBODY]; Tue, 25 Feb 2014 09:30:42 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=[MYDOMAIN];
 i=@[MYDOMAIN]; q=dns/txt; s=critsend2; t=1393320642;
 h=MIME-Version : From : To : Subject : Content-Transfer-Encoding :
 Message-ID : List-Unsubscribe : Precedence : Content-Type;
 bh=VtkeZ6tV/XFMlAtluMsv26PzGvObCK+iI+sGcdRcD1M=; b=easlojoKgkQoaXt8EYcIJpHd0HuOq60XMRYpwrbQZZLndX2Yj2IqEdqheDzo8UXF2CTZfmk3uySAXK2xu7U4UxEEvB1jkKSTwC+WtDiCQUzMZkFK/59KGA113Znf6VbN6Z4qoP/JVo0Fw/FOrYnALGpQ/zRToE9kHZ7lapQZsJA=
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "[MYSELF]" <2013@[MYDOMAIN]>
To:[SOMEBODY]
Subject: Test 1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-ID: <4+paasltcrblbsaecf2ecqsq6ugzg563umj3gyaorqrx5w6qz6f4d655s4qdhdelav3itvw3lmvytwsoztobumxur7hjdutj7iec2quohazor3b6ixmwj7gcwk3iar7xzrqzsx2bakdnifl757tn7m2yrd4e======+75030@critsend.com>
List-Unsubscribe: 
Precedence: bulk
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 09:30:42 +0000 (UTC)`

**SPF**
`recordtype: spf 
name: [MYDOMAIN] 
value: v=spf1 mx include:messaging-master.com ~all

recordtype: txt 
name: [MYDOMAIN] 
value: v=spf1 mx include:messaging-master.com ~all`
http://critsend.freshdesk.com/support/articles/101362-how-can-i-setup-my

**DKIM**
`recordtype: txt 
name: critsend2._domainkey.[MYDOMAIN] 
value: k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvEpIr9ILg7iXsdMlMst5sCK+MDc4GQDaZDmgLLHHVNn952Jh4zmB1Qp+fBSUzVfcU/qW4hicOMJKRe0bo8nIB/Gvh3CtJuyAFizXCUjDtn2V4t5rg2OEpVkEXHkwUoW43Z5753Q62flW2wb3zuEqoO5fWLUt4rcIqatE+O8zmSwIDAQAB`

http://critsend.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/101348-how-can-i-setup-my-dkim-

When I run [MYDOMAIN] against the usual test tools (http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html, http://dkimcore.org/tools/keycheck.html) I receive for both a result which should have been sufficient for the email to be sent correctly.

Any ideas on correctly configure/use critsend with my own domain, without any reference to critsend?

--

Solution found: The problem was indeed with the SPF/DKIM key configuration of for the domains. As @mxx said just precisely follow their documentation found online and you will be fine.

PS 
Having a SPF-SPF and a TXT-SPF is no problem at all.

Comment: If you don't want them to relay your email, don't relay your email through them.. the service they offer is relaying.

Comment: @NickW, but sorry did I misunderstand this http://support.critsend.com/support/solutions/articles/101241-why-should-i-setup-a-dkim-and-spf- wrong? I thought this means that I can set up a domain that the on behalf does no longer appear?!

Comment: I think you just misconfigured your email client.

Comment: I should have been more specific: We are using a web based newsletter tool, which has been coded by our team. The email address we use is set in the configuration of critsend and the script uses credentials given by them to us to send the emails. This should, if I understood the documentation correctly, in no 'via' or 'on behalf' in the receivers end.

Comment: Wait, exactly which header are you objecting to?

Comment: @NickW ... sorry I am the idiot here. The header above is fine and works precisely as intended. I am using this on three domains, but for the other two I receive:  dkim=fail header.i=@[MYDOMAIN2&3]... even though the recommended test tool of critsend (http://dkimcore.org/tools/keycheck.html) claims all is ok if I test it with the critsend2 key.

Comment: Ahhh, maybe you should look at sections 2 of this : http://critsend.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/101362-how-can-i-set-up-my-spf-

Comment: @NickW thanks I have got it working on 2/3 like this, but the last one  just wont work, I have defined the email as helpdesk@[MYDOMAIN] several days ago, the DKIM comes back positive, but still the via critsend.com in the email header.

Comment: @mebu83 based on what you posted in your question, your SPF and DKIM settings are wrong. For SPF your DNS record should be type of `txt`, not spf. Your DKIM is completely wrong. Read your own critsend links, it tells you what DKIM records should be.

Comment: @Mxx thanks, I have added the SPF record as recommended by one of the linked test tools by critsend. If having a SPF-SPF and a TXT-SPF record at the same time is harmful or wrong I of course would remove it. But various tools confirmed that they are correct. Regarding the DKIM, sorry that was a copy paste error, I have corrected the question text accordingly. Thanks again for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed with the SPF/DKIM key configuration of for the domains. As @mxx said just precisely follow their documentation found online and you will be fine.

PS Having a SPF-SPF and a TXT-SPF is no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

The return email address is a setting in your email client, when you create an account, use your email, and domain. The only place a system like critsend will need to have a `@critsend.com` email address, will be in your STMP Auth settings, either on your relaying mailserver or on your email client, if you send email directly via their servers.